# idangero.us swiper update tabs on slide swipe

Tags: javascript, jquery

Building a mobile a mobile app demo using the idangero.us swiper:

http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/

I've *almost* got it working the way I want, with one issue:

When you click on one of the tabs in the menu, it changes it's class to "active" and slides to the proper slide. What I need to do is also change the tab class when a user manually swipes one of the slides. So if you swipe to the "about us" slide for example, the corresponding tab should change to active.

There's an example of this in action here:

["Tabs with Feedback"](http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/demos.php)

I just can't figure out how to make that work when I have two swipers on the page (one for the nav, and one for the body).

Here's the js:

```
$(function(){
//Init Navigation
var nav = $('.swiper-nav').swiper({
slidesPerView: 'auto',
freeMode:true,
freeModeFluid:true,
onSlideClick: function(nav){
pages.swipeTo( nav.clickedSlideIndex )
}
})

$(".swiper-nav a").on('touchstart mousedown',function(e){
e.preventDefault()
$(".swiper-nav .active").removeClass('active')
$(this).addClass('active')
tabsSwiper.swipeTo( $(this).index() )
})
$(".swiper-nav a").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault()
})

//Init Pages
var pages = $('.swiper-pages').swiper()

})
```

[Fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/tactics/MX8W6/)

Thanks.

Comment: @dongseok() solution below works. I enhanced it a bit and updated the fiddle above to perfection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use onSlideChangeEnd callback from swiper API.

```
//Init Pages
var pages = $('.swiper-pages').swiper({
    onSlideChangeEnd: function(swiper, direction) {
        $(".swiper-nav .active").removeClass('active');
        $(".swiper-nav li:nth-child("+(swiper.activeIndex+1)+") a").addClass('active');
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MX8W6/4/)

Comment: Thanky you @dongseok0. That did the trick. I edited your script slightly because when you clicked on a link, the class was changing to active, but the previously active li retained its class. So now I'm removing both (Fiddle updated)

The only issue now is that you can't always see the active tab. To see what I mean, shrink your browser down to phone size. Swipe the body to the "services" slide. See how the corresponding tab is partially obscured? Any way to change the active tab's position in the nav on swipe and click?